# Extract the text from ArcGIS map using JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

[image: Arcgis Basemap]

I have this map, and I'm looking to extract the map label when clicked on the map.
Let's suppose I click on the block with a `16257038`. How can I get this text using JavaScript API. Here is my code so far

```js
const view = new MapView({container: "viewDiv", map: map});
view.on("click", function (evt) {
          let loc = evt.mapPoint;
          let lng = Math.round(loc.longitude * 100000) / 100000;
          let lat = Math.round(loc.latitude * 100000) / 100000;
          // how to get the text label from the map

});
```

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy.  Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code sample. However, I think you could still show a little more more effort. What have you tried to get the text label?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to find anything remotely that could get the text label.